# Remove records from table, if its specific value does not appears in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete, notin

I have two tables. `T1` has `t1field1` and `t1field2`, and `T2` has `t2field1` and `t2field2`.
I want to remove all records from `T2`, if `t2field1` value does not exist in `t1field1`

```
+----------+----------+
| t1field1 | t1field2 |
+----------+----------+
|   1      |    x     |
|   5      |    y     |
|   6      |    z     |
+----------+----------+

+----------+----------+
| t2field1 | t2field2 |
+----------+----------+
|   3      |    x     |
|   4      |    y     |
|   5      |    z     |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE t2
FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.t1field1 = t2.t2field1
WHERE t1.t1field1 IS NULL
```

**OR**

```
DELETE FROM t2 WHERE t2.t2field1 NOT IN (SELECT t1.t1field1 FROM t1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete t2
from t2
left join t1 on t1.t1field1 = t2.field1
where t1.field1 is null
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  DELETE FROM T2 
  WHERE t2field1 NOT IN (SELECT t1field1 FROM T1)
```